# "Add to Source Control" option when making a new C# project in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, new-operator

When I go to make a new C# Windows application in VS 2010, there is an option at the bottom **right** area with a check box saying **add to source**.

I want to know what happens, if I check it and create the new C# file.

Comment: BTW, there is no such thing as "C#.Net".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it actually says, "Add to Source Control."  That will register the project with whichever source control plugin you have enabled in VS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a source control plugin configured to work with Visual Studio, checking that box will create the new application in the source control in a manner defined by the plugin that you're using.